# Flutter Stack and Card using

Tags: user-interface, flutter, frontend

I want it to look like the first picture, but I couldn't find a way, please help?

I try to stack and positioned widget for this but when i use positioned widget top or left negative value my container doesnt seem i couldn't handle it.

my main problem is i can't get the green circle container out of the card area

[image]
[image]

```
Stack(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                          child: Center(
                            child: Container(
                              width: 52,
                              height: 52,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Color(0xffDCDCDC),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Positioned(
                          top: 0,
                          left: 0,
                          child: Container(
                            width: 31,
                            height: 19,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                              color: Color(0xffE9E9E9),
                            ),
                            child: Container(
                              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 12),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                  color: Colors.white),
                              child: Container(
                                width: 15,
                                height: 15,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                    color: Color(0xff5CE02E)),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
```

Comment: Please share what you get with your code.

Comment: increase the top and left value in the Positioned widget.

Comment: How are the first and second pictures different?

Comment: the green circle in the first picture is outside the card area

Answer (score 0):

```
Stack(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                          child: Center(
                            child: Container(
                              width: 52,
                              height: 52,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Color(0xffDCDCDC),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Positioned(
                          top: 10,
                          left: 10,
                          child: Container(
                            width: 31,
                            height: 19,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                              color: Color(0xffE9E9E9),
                            ),
                            child: Container(
                              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 12),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                  color: Colors.white),
                              child: Container(
                                width: 15,
                                height: 15,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                    color: Color(0xff5CE02E)),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
```